# What permission am missing?

Tags: android, sms, backup, permission-denied

I'm taking sms backup using this

```
public void smsbackup() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db");

        File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/bcfile");
        dir.mkdirs();

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.android.app/files/");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0) 
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        in.close();
    }
```

It throws an exception like `permission denied` I don't know what permission will i give. Anyone tell me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: lol! what are the permissions you are using already?

Comment: You should look through your exception log, it shows what permission you're missing.

Comment: Also in the future it is really helpful if you post the Stacktrace from LogCat

Comment: @Sherif : These are all my permissions list for my application - http://pastebin.com/QyXAN5Cp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

because of

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/bcfile");
```

---

I wonder if you can ever access: `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`

Comment: By the way, why are you making this dir. It isn't used.

Comment: @Sherif : Then, which one is used? Am already give this permission.

Comment: `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` this file! you can not access it because it is not your package. Show us logcat

Comment: @SPK even if you add all the permissions! You can not access `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` I think you can access it if you have root access only !

Comment: @Sherif : Nice. I've tried lot of times for root access. No one gave a perfect reply or answer. Anyway i'll try.

Comment: @Sherif : Do you know how to get root access for Android-Emulator.

Comment: I never tried it.. But I do not think that it is something you do by code! It is a process you do for the phone! some sort of a hack to get the root access

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

you have to add this permission since you are trying to write files to SDcard. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

You also need the permission of reading inbox messages.

Hope it will help you